# Finding files for playing sound

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to make an application where when I click a JButton, it plays a song. I've already figured out how to specify JButtons. However, I can't seem to find a way to play sound. I'm not going to use sun.audio, so many of the threads that I looked at didnt work. I found many low quality answers. Eventually, I settled on this code.

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
        Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Inside my src folder, I have a folder called "Songs". I changed the file path to this:
/Songs/

Then, I tried calling the function using a wav file:

```
playSound("song.wav");
```

And then I get a null error. I believe that this is because it does not recognize the file path. The answer to my problem is most likely very obvious, but somehow I cant find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put song.wav in the same folder of your Main class, then the getResourceAsStream will find it.

if you're using eclipse, it can automatically copy the .wav file to the output folder.

You might want to create a class on some different java package so your entry point does not get polluted by assets.

This reading might help you: http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading